# How to reset Glsurfaceview's render object

Tags: android, glsurfaceview

Can I reset the GLSurfaceView.Renderer object for GLSurfaceView ?

Comment: What does reset mean here - change to another renderer ? How are you setting it now ?

Comment: GLSurfaceView mGLView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.myCustomSurface);
mGLView.setRenderer(mRenderer); 

and then I want to change the render instance (mRender2)

mGLView.setRenderer(mRenderer2) ;

but it cause the exception.

Comment: From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setRenderer%28android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer%29 - "This method should be called once and only once in the life-cycle of a GLSurfaceView. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  The API doesn't work that way.

Instead, use a single method with an if/then or switch statement that causes it to change behavior.

If you don't like that approach, use a plain SurfaceView and provide your own EGL setup and threading classes.  Then you can render however you like, and can even take advantage of things like Choreographer to reduce latency.  See [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) for examples.